# Constructing a POST request to a rest server in c#

Tags: c#, rest, post, http-headers

I am attempting to construct a POST request to a REST server, based on the following documentation:

http://appsensor.org/docs/v2.3.0/api/ui/index.html#!/RestRequestHandler/resource_RestRequestHandler_addEvent_POST

I have been using the following code that I have written:

```
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> events()
    {
        try
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:8085/");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException)
        { }
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("X-Appsensor-Client-Application-Name2", "myclientapp");
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/v1.0/events");
        request.Content = new StringContent("AE3",
                                            Encoding.UTF8,
                                            "application/json");//CONTENT-TYPE header


        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1.0/events", request);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.ToString());
        return response;
    }
```

But this is the response I get:

```
StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:

{
  Connection: close
  Date: Sun, 04 Mar 2018 23:46:17 GMT
  Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
  Content-Length: 402
  Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
}
```

What is it about the post request that is incorrect?

Comment: According to the swagger you have linked, you are passing "AE3" as the content while the API expects a JSON object with a lot of data.

Comment: I'm wondering, why does the request object need "api/v1.0/events" as part of new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "api/v1.0/events");   since this url path is already included in the call client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/v1.0/events", request);

Comment: @AnthonyMcGrath PostAsJsonAsync required more than one argument, a request Uri and a Value, I wasn't sure about including it a second time but it seemed necessary. The same goes for the HttpRequestMessage, requiring a method and a request Uri.

Comment: @Gusman AE3 refers to an ID of an authentication exception, which can be found here:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/AppSensor_DetectionPoints#AE3:_High_Rate_of_Login_Attempts

Should I be making "AE3" into a JSON object?

Comment: @ImranRahman Go to the swagger you have linked in the question and open the request to api/v1.0/events, there you will find what you must pass to the API